Are tiny relays with high current problematic?
Goal:
Build a climate room with a fridge, heater, dryer, humidifier, and a fan. The power to the components shall be controllable with relays connected to a Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi will read the humidity and the temperature in the fridge and start devices based on the read data. What I want to make is close to what BrewPi do in Method 1
Device Info

The most power demanding device is the fridge ARC 0451/1, which uses 54 W.
My home has 240 V.

Choice of Relay
I need help to choose the type of relay:

ELEGOO 8 Channel DC 5V Relay Module with Optocoupler 
HiLetgo

Both are sufficient on paper. However, I need a stronger power source than the pins of the Raspberry Pi to turn on the relays. I will use a Power Supply Adapter 5V for that purpose.
The ELAGOO is the weaker one, but it can handle up to 10 A which is more than needed.
ELAGOO  Pros

Cheaper
Takes up less space than 5 HiLetgo relays.
It includes an optocoupler. If I go with the other option, I will need to buy optocouplers (or transistors and diodes).

HiLetgo Pros

It's larger and “feels” more robust

I am just worried considering the high voltage the ELAGOO will get too warm. Will the ELAGOO work, or am I right of being skeptical? Would it help for safety if I add a 6 A or 10 A circuit breaker? The fridge does not specify the current needed during startup, but I hope 6 A is fine.

54W? really? does that include the starting load? Did you measure it? if not, you should and all the other devices as well.

I would recommend to check the reviews of both devices. What is your power supply for the controller? Apparently the elagoo devices require a far share of current for itself.

The Diamond Pros will probably contain a typical optocoupler input as well. The Pi outputs should be capable of driving these inputs directly. There is no datasheet, so buy one and test it.

Is this a Ken and Barbie doll house? What heater or refrigerator uses 54 watts?

You can buy WiFi relays that are compliant with your local electrical regulations fairly cheaply. This avoids you having to do  any electrical wiring yourself. It might also avoid the need for the raspi. FYI any fusing or circuit breakers are to protect the wiring not the load. Eg if your wiring is rated for 6A, then there should be a CB or fuse rated for 6A.

I've updated my question with a picture of the specs of the fridge, with a link to the separate power supply to the relays, and updated the goal.

@Jens: What are "Diamond Pros"?

@Kartman : Such as Sonoff Basic R2?

Yes and various devices from athom.tech and others. If they run Tasmota, you can program them to do just about anything.

@Kartman Thanks for the link. It seems to be cheaper to buy such products than to build it myself, the tradeoff is that the ready-to-buy-product is wireless which I dislike.

@Bojack Sorry, I wanted to refer to Diamore, now called HiLetgo after the edit.

@SolarMike What tool do I need to measure the starting load?

The two are different technology - SSR vs. mechanical relay, with different characteristics (SSRs produce much more heat for a given load current and often require heat sinks or fans, relays can weld and wear out - at best after 100,000 operations at full load - ideally with the best possible resistive load and more optimal switching than that board provides). They have different failure modes which should be evaluated and appropriate safety devices specified where necessary.
Some of your loads qualify as 'nasty' (inductive and/or with start-up surges). 54W for a fridge seems very low. Compressors normally have a really nasty start-up surge and use much more beefy relays than those- at probably >20x the cost per relay.
You are looking at rather low-end hobbyist-grade switching devices that may not even meet the claimed specs.
If I was doing this, I'd probably end up (after a detailed evaluation of each and every load and the required system and life requirements) using something like individual Omron G7L relays.

I've updated my question with a picture of the specs of the fridge. I agree that ELAGOO seem very hobbyist-grade.  Does the other relay I linked also belong in this group?

Elegoo is a known (in hobbyist circles anyway) company, and Songle is an actual relay manufacturer and you can look up datasheets for the relays, though interpretation might be necessary if you're not very familiar with relay ratings. The SSR has a name I've never heard of, has no proper datasheet (and there's conflicting information in the ad) - how do you know how big a heat sink you need? What kind of snubber?  And the market on eBay, Amazon etc. is filled with fake SSRs, some of which are garbage counterfeits of more reputable Chinese makers such as Fotek. Since that's become well known..

A backward dioder is needed for the relay as well, right?
The relay will be connected to the start relay of the fridge and not directly to the compressor. Will a snubber be needed then?
